# Why does imwrite on BMP image gets stuck / does not return?

Tags: c++, opencv, bitmap

I am reading a Bitmap-file from disk and write a copy back to disk after some manipulation, also writing a copy of the original file. The bitmaps are relatively small with a resolution of `31 x 31` pixel.

What I see is that when I have a resolution of `30 x 30` pixel then `cv::imwrite` correctly writes out the files, however if I go for a resolution of `31 x 31` pixel then `cv:imwrite` just gets stuck and does not return. This is happening on the same directories.

```
<...>
image = cv::imread(imageName, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE); // Read the file
if( image.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}
Mat image_flip (width,height,CV_8U);

int8_t pixel_8b;
for (int i=0; i< width; i++){
    for (int j=0; j < height; j++){
        pixel_8b= image.at<int8_t>(i,j);
        image_flip.at<int8_t>(width-i,j) = pixel_8b;
    }
}
cout << "Writing files" << endl;
result=cv::imwrite("./output_flip.bmp", image_flip);

cout << result << endl;
return 0;
```

In the good case I get the file `output_flip.bmp` written to the disk and `result` is displayed. In the bad case of being stuck the last thing I see is "Writing files" and then nothing anymore. I can switch back and forth between the good and the bad case by just resizing the input image.

Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Comment: It is quite hard for OpenCV to deal with images with a resolution that is not a multiple of 8. But 30 isn't :D but at least is even. I think 31 might be too small and too specific for OpenCV. I have had similar problems and I delaed with them using IPLimages and hard-setting their `image.aligmnet`

Comment: What is the ```result``` ,```width``` and ```height``` how did you assign them. Please share the whole code!!!

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use BMP format files? They are really quite a poor choice because Microsoft never published a definitive, unambiguous specification, and they are not space efficient and don't support 16-bit data.

Answer (score 2):

As already discussed in the comments, you didn't provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE). So, I derived the following MRE from your code, because I wanted to point out several things (and wondered, how your code could work at all):

```cpp
#include <opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("path/to/your/image.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(30, 30));

    cv::Mat image_flip(image.size().height, image.size().width, CV_8U);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.size().width; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.size().height; j++) 
        {
            const uint8_t pixel_8b = image.at<uint8_t>(j, i);
            image_flip.at<uint8_t>(j, image.size().width - 1 - i) = pixel_8b;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Writing files" << std::endl;
    const bool result = cv::imwrite("./output_flip.bmp", image_flip);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- For single channel, 8-bit image (`CV_8U`), use `uint8_t` when accessing single pixels.
- When using `.at`, please notice, that the syntax is `.at(y, x)`. For square images, it might be equal, but in general, it's a common source for errors.
- Accessing `.at(j, width-i)` MUST fail for `i = 0`, if `width = image.size().width`, since the last index of `image` is `width - 1`.

After correcting these issues, I could run your code without problems for larger images, as well as resized images to `30 x 30` or `31 x 31`. So, please have a look, if you can resolve your issue(s) by modifying your code accordingly.

(I'm aware, that the actual issue as stated in the question (hanging `imwrite`) is not addressed at all in my answer, but as I said, I couldn't even run the provided code in the first place...)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @HansHirse, I feel so young again, i.e. inexperienced. 8o(
Overseeing the missing "-1" was actually the main cause here.  Also thanks a lot for pointing out the (y,x) vs. (x,y).